# Python for loop multiplication

Tags: python

Learning python on grok learning and have been a bit stumped on this problem. I need a program to produce this output:

```
Enter a negative number: -6
720
```

The formula is: `-1 x -2 x -3 x -4 x -5 x -6 = -720`

My Code:

```
n = int(input('Enter a negative number: '))
result = 0
for i in range(-1*n):
    result = result + i 
print(result)
```

Comment: The statements inside a `for` loop have to be indented.

Comment: What is the formula you're supposed to be implementing? Adding the numbers from `0` to `5` will just return `15`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm supposed to enter -6 and it produce 720               
 -1 x -2 x -3 x -4 x -5 x -6 = 720

Comment: Your formula shows multiplication, but your code is doing addition.

Answer (score 0):

If `n = 6`, then `range(-1 * n)` will be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Those aren't the numbers you want, you want `-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1`. To get that sequence, you should use `range(n, 0)`.

And you're supposed to multiply, not add. That also means you need to initialize the result with `1`, not `0`, because multiplying by `0` is always `0`.

```
n = int(input('Enter a negative number: '))
result = 1
for i in range(n, 0):
    result *= i
print(result)
```

Comment: aaaaa I see! Thank you! Result = 1 is that to set the increments  by 1???

Comment: No, `range()` increments by 1 by default.

Comment: Grade school arithmetic: if you multiply anything by 0, you get 0. You have to start with `1` if you're multiplying.

Comment: Barmar, your range examples are wrong. `range(-6)` and `range(6, 0)` both result in `[]`.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson It should be `range(-6, 0)`